# How do I center this container?

Tags: html, css, containers

How do I center this container so that it is centered from the top, left, and right? I have tried what I have below but it won't work.   Not sure what I am missing:

```
 HTML: 

<div class="box"> 
     <p>This is a sentence.</p>
</div>

 CSS:

 .box {
 background-color: #444444;
 color: #888888;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 position: absolute;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: try to remove `position: absolute;`

Comment: Could just put padding on the left, right, top, and bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` and it will center ..

This is because absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the document flow .. and because no other element is using the `position` property your div is relative to the root `<html>` element .. hence why it stays at the top-left of the viewport.

Comment: If you want to center with absolute positioning use left:50%;margin-left:-500px;

Comment: Thanks that worked but how about centering it from the top? Just use margin-top?

Comment: you cannot vertically align in center of window using CSS as far as I know. You will have to use javascript after pageload to detect window height.

Comment: You can use `position: absolute;` in that case and set `top: 50%;` and `left: 50%;` and you'll get the bar in the middle of the browser.

Comment: won't top:50% position it to 50% of the containing element? I would think it would not be visible on page load if the containing element has higher than double the window height.

Comment: but is the root html element stretching to the window size? What if the window height was increased?

Comment: since it's defined using the `%` value it will grow with the browser and stay centered ..

Comment: What would happen if the html element had a height of 5000px?

Comment: but you mean centered in the html element and not the window? I think his goal is to center vertically in the window when the page loads.

Comment: Okay, I have tested and you are correct my friend. Giving your answer a +1.